# ComboBox no valid source for component creation

Tags: java, combobox, jcombobox

I got a problem trying to implement JcomboBox,once i use it, swingBuilder were no able to display it anymore, show me a error message: `new JComboBox<String>(tempValuesArray) is not valid source for component creation, it references not existing constructor.` 
No sure why, how can i solve it?

Comment: @MichaelPickett [Look again.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html)

Comment: The element type of your array must match the generic type of the JComboBox.  So `new JComboBox<String>(tempValuesArray)` requires that tempValuesArray be of type `String[]`.

Comment: @VGR I see now. I was looking at outdated things.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have the same problem using eclipse window builder, although the element type of my array matches the type of the JComboBox.

```
private JComboBox<String> newDvdCategoryComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(categories);
```